# Can a corollary depend on another corollary?

Tags: proof-writing

Is it good or bad practice to have a corollary depend heavily on another corollary?

An alternative approach would be to state one of the corollarys as a theorem.

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: Neither good nor bad in the abstract. Structure your work so it's easiest for the reader.